# Don't change varriable value after first call

Tags: android, call

I'm new android/java programmer and I can't find anywhere how to set default varriable value only on first call. My console log delete after second call. My code looks like:

```
public class Ftp {
 [...]
 //Console
 String console_strings[] = new String [15];
 int console_line = 0;
 //

 [...]
 public void drawConsole(String msg){

    CharSequence time  = DateFormat.format("hh:mm:ss", d.getTime());
    String message = "["+time+"] "+msg;
    TextView console = (TextView)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.console);
    String newString = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < console_strings.length; i++){

            if(console_strings[i] != null)
                newString += console_strings[i] + "\n";
            else
            {
                console_strings[i] = message;
                newString += console_strings[i] + "\n";
                break;
            }
        }
console.setText(newString);
  }

}
```

Whenever I want to add something to the console, it delete old text value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. The problem you are having is that you are setting the entire textview's text at once. You could do one of a few things. You could do

```
console.setText(console.getText() + newString);
```

or

```
console.append(newString);
```

Both of these would work. There are multiple other ways, but those should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

`TextView` has also an `append` method